# How to properly notify view layer to open a dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dialog, viewmodel

I have a WPF application and i'm trying to respect the MVVM pattern rules. One of my views contains button:

```
                <Button
                    Command="{Binding BrowseCommand}"
                    Margin="50, 0, 0, 0"
                    Style="{StaticResource CommonButtonStyle}"
                    Width="100"
                    Height="30">
                    <TextBlock
                        Text="Browse"/>
                </Button>
```

Button command calls a method:

```
private void Browse(object sender)
{

    DialogService.BrowseForDestinationPath(DestinationPath);

}
```

The main purpose of this method is to show "Select-directory-dialog", collect data and return it to the view model.

```
    public static class DialogService
    {

        public static event Action<string> FolderBrowseRequested;

        ...

        public static void BrowseForDestinationPath(string initialPath)
        {

            FolderBrowseRequested?.Invoke(initialPath);

        }

    }
```

Event defined in my DialogService class is invoked, and the subscriber method located in code-behind of the dialog fires:

```
        protected void OnFolderBrowseRequested(string initialPath)
        {

            string destinationPath = initialPath;
            var browsingDialog = new VistaFolderBrowserDialog();

            if(browsingDialog.ShowDialog(this).GetValueOrDefault())
            {

                destinationPath = browsingDialog.SelectedPath;
                var dataContext = DataContext as UnpackArchiveWindowViewModel;

                if (dataContext != null)
                    dataContext.DestinationPath = destinationPath;

            }

            DialogService.FolderBrowseRequested -= OnFolderBrowseRequested; //so dumb

        }
```

The problem is i really don't like this solution, I'm convinced it's unnecessarily complicated and inelegant. How to properly show a dialog on button click, collect some data and deliver it to our view model? I would like to keep View and ViewModel seperated and fully respect MVVM regime.

Comment: Welcome to SO! No matter how you approach it, good MVVM dialog box implementation is non-trivial. What matters is whether you want to do it yourself or use a library to do the hard lifting for you. Have a read of [this article I wrote](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820324/Implementing-Dialog-Boxes-in-MVVM) and the associated library package, it may meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much, for the article, it contains great, precise explanation, i found it very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You could first start by describing the behavior your DialogService needs in an interface.

```
public interface IDialogService
{
    void BrowseForDestinationPath(string initialPath);

    event PathSelectedEvent PathSelected;
}
public delegate void PathSelectedEvent(string destinationPath);
```

Your ViewModel would contain a member of type IDialogService and subscribe to the PathSelectedEvent. The BrowseForDestinationPath method would be called using your Browse method which is called using the Command.

You could then create a user control which implements IDialogService. You could either inject this through your ViewModels constructor or if your ViewModel had a property like

```
public IDialogService FolderBorwser {get;set;}
```

the benefit of this approach is that all your view model knows about is an interface. You now delegate the responsibility of creating a concrete instance to something else. I would reccomend using an Injection Container like Unity or MEF as they handle the job of managing and resolving dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to write your own logic because it helps you to understand the problem of opening dialogs in MVVM, but if you hit a brick wall or wan't to take the easy way out, there is a library called [MVVM Dialogs](https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs) that can help you with these problems.

Using this library you would write your code like this.

```
private void Browse(object sender)
{
  var settings = new FolderBrowserDialogSettings
  {
    Description = "This is a description"
  };

  bool? success = dialogService.ShowFolderBrowserDialog(this, settings);
  if (success == true)
  {
    // Do something with 'settings.SelectedPath'
  }
}
```